# Why can't I use my static resource in a resource dictionary in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, staticresource

I designed my control (radio button) using a `ResourceDictionary` like this:

```xml
//in SidebarMenuButtonTheme.xaml

<Style TargetType="{x:Type custom:MenuItem}"
        x:Key="MenuButtonTheme">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type custom:MenuItem}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="SidebarRadioButtonMenuText"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}"                             
                                Foreground="#7D8083"
                                FontSize="14.59"
                                FontFamily="{StaticResource NunitoBold}" />
                </Grid>               
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The `FontFamily` works just fine when I define the `Source`: e.g.

```xml
FontFamily="/UiDesign/Fonts/#Nunito"
```

But when I use `StaticResource` for the `FontFamily`

```xml
FontFamily="{StaticResource NunitoBold}"
```

I receive this error in my UI:

[image]

(The error is: The element [MenuItem] of type MenuItem could not be displayed)

This is how I declare my font resource in my App.xaml

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UiDesign/Theme/SidebarMenuButtonTheme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <FontFamily x:Key="NunitoBold">/UiDesign/Fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf#Nunito</FontFamily>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I don't know why this is giving an error, even though intellisense works when I type `StaticResource`:

[image]

But when I define my `FontFamily` resource **in** the `ResourceDictionary`, the menu items will display just fine.

```xml
//I added this above my Style tag...
<FontFamily x:Key="NunitoBold">/UiDesign/Fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf#Nunito</FontFamily>
```

**Update:**
But, when I use the `StaticResource` (for the font) in a `UserControl`, I can use it just fine. My problem here is that, **can I use the resource in App.xaml, in a ResourceDictionay?**

Comment: To solve this problem, we need to see your Solution Explorer structure. Can you show me?

Comment: @james.lee there was some missing information in my post, I updated it now...

Comment: Move your fontfamily declaration into your resource dictionary, before where you reference it.

Comment: @Andy I did that, and it works, but when I declare the fontfamily in the App.xaml, the fontfamily will not apply (even if intellisense recognizes it)

Comment: @Andy do I need to create a "fontfamily" resource in each of my resource dictionaries?

Comment: It needs to be there before it's used. You can define font resources in a resource dictionary of it's own. But merge it before your resource dictionaries reference those fonts.

Comment: What do you mean "merge"? This is not familiar to me, this is my first time creating ui in wpf.

Comment: You see where you have mergeddictionaries? This is where you can put numerous resource dictionaries that you're merging. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/systems/xaml-resources-merged-dictionaries?view=netdesktop-5.0

Comment: @Andy oh yeah, that one. I already did. It's on my post already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a solution for this, instead of using `StaticResource` I used `DynamicResource` instead. Now I can access my fonts from `App.xaml` to my `ResourceDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reference the font using a [pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077):

```
<FontFamily x:Key="NunitoBold">pack://application:,,,/UiDesign/Fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf#Nunito</FontFamily>
```

You also need to ensure that the paths is correct, i.e. that `UiDesign` is a folder at the root of your project in which the `Fonts` folder with the font is located.

Comment: This didn't work too, give me an error: Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.' I know that I have the right folder paths because the intellisense recognized "NunitoBold" x key

Comment: If you get that error, you are trying to reference a resource that cannot be found.